# how to use the msql trigger to update a column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

As illustrated in the image below, I want the column grand_score to be automatically calculated when values for paper_score and final_score are inserted.

This is what i have tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTableAutoSum
BEFORE INSERT ON `stumgr_scores` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.grand_score= NEW.paper_score + NEW.final_score;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Issue

when i input values for  paper_score and final_score, the table does not get updated (i mean grand_score)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK0Lb.png)

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Comment: when i input values for  paper_score and final_score, the table does not get updated (i mean grand_score)

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see what is wrong with your trigger, unless one of the values happens to be `NULL`.  That is easily fixed using `COALESCE()`:

```
SET NEW.grand_score = COALESCE(NEW.paper_score, 0) + COALESCE(NEW.final_score, 0);
```

I question the use of triggers for this purpose.  You also need a trigger for `UPDATE`, in case the values change that way.

Isn't simpler to remove `grand_total` from the table and use a view?

```
create view v_stumgr_scores as
    select ss.*,
           COALESCE(ss.paper_score, 0) + COALESCE(ss.final_score, 0) as grand_score
    from stumgr_scores ss;
```

Or, better yet, in the most recent versions of MySQL, just use a generated column.  That is the best solution -- it even allows you to create an index on the value.

Comment: thank you. so this will solve my problem of auto updating the column (grand_score) when values for paper_score and final_score are entered.

Comment: @FavourChukwuedo . . . Both the view and the generated columns (in some version of 5.7) do the calculation when you query the table.  That is guarantees that the latest data is being used.